# Sqoop connect with SQL Anywhere 17

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, apache-nifi, sqoop, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to get sqoop to work with sqlanywhere17's `sajdbc4.jar`. I keep getting library errors for the command not being able to find `.so` related files needed with the jar.

Now, I've created a symbolic link to `sajdbc4.jar -> /opt/sqlanywhere17/java/sajdbc4.jar` inside of `/usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib/`.

```
ln -s  /opt/sqlanywhere17/java/sajdbc4.jar /usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib/sajdbc4.jar
```

**I'm getting this error:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dbjdbc17 in java.library.path

**After following [this guide](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/Installing+SQL+Anywhere+17+on+Ubuntu+14.04) and [this documentation](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbprogramming/pg-jdbc-4-0-load.html):**

```
cat /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh >> ~/.bashrc
cat /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh >> ~/.bash_profile
```

And checking `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  :

```
/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64:/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64/client:/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64/server:/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64:/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64/native_threads:
```

And checking the java.library.path for : `/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64`

**Command Line:**

```
  java -XshowSettings:properties
```

---

```
Property settings:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    com.sap.vm.codeline = 81_REL
    com.sap.vm.compressedoops = true
    com.sap.vm.profilingserver = true
    com.sap.vm.type = opt
    com.sap.vm.version = 10
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = /
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path = .
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/ext-sap
        /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/ext
        /usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home = /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64
        /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64/client
        /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64/server
        /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64
        /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64/native_threads
         
        /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
        /usr/lib64
        /lib64
        /lib
        /usr/lib
```

---

**Full Error:**

```
    19/10/22 08:30:05 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.5.3.0-37
19/10/22 08:30:07 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
19/10/22 08:30:07 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dbjdbc17 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver.try_load(IDriver.java:451)
        at sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver.<clinit>(IDriver.java:413)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:873)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.EvalSqlTool.run(EvalSqlTool.java:64)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)
[root@server1 dag_scripts]# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64:/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64/client:/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64/server:/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64:/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/jre180/lib/amd64/native_threads:
```

---

---

Answer (score 0):

This solution appears to fix the problem for now:

- `ln -s  /opt/sqlanywhere17/java/sajdbc4.jar /usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib/sajdbc4.jar`
- Pick either `/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib32` or `/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/` based on 32 bit / 64 bit requirements
- Create a symbolic link to your current JDK path and JVM path
- Open permissions for accessing `/opt/sqlanywhere17/java/` if you installed as root
- Ensure user is part of "hadoop" group - for sqoop folder permissions (.env)
- Add the default exports to any user running the sqoop command

  ```
   ln -s /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/* /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/jre/lib/amd64/

   ln -s /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/* /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-1.el7_7.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/

   chmod 755 -R /opt/sqlanywhere17/*
   usermod -a -G hadoop user

   #For user executing sqoop:
   cat /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh >> ~/.bashrc
  ```

---

**Sqoop Commands for testing:**

**For sajdbc4.jar:**

```
sqoop eval --connect 'jdbc:sqlanywhere:Host=192.168.1.11:1234;ServerName=DemoServer;DatabaseName=demo' --driver sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver --username testuser --P --query "SELECT * from database.table"
```

**For jconn4:**

You can also place the jconn4.jar into sqoop's lib directory.

`/usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib/sajdbc4.jar`

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBCON/Software+Developer+Kit+for+ASE+driver+versions+for+Windows

```
sqoop eval --connect 'jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.1.11:1234' --driver com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver --username testuser --P --query "SELECT * from database.table"
```

---

**For NiFi running SqlAnywhere17 in a DBCPConnectionPool:**

Removing all the symbolic links and `.bashrc` profile settings and instead attaching the config for sqlanywhere (`/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh`) into "NiFi Node Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for nifi-env.sh". I was able to get the libs to load properly. The connection now works in NiFi!

The only interesting bug is that if I create 2 DBCPConnectionPool's with both of them using the driver, one of the queries will fail and say:  `failed to process session due to Native Library /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbjdbc17.so.1 already loaded in another classloader; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbjdbc17.so.1 already loaded in another classloader`

So currently we are using 1 connection using sajdbc4.jar and our workaround was to use jconn4.jar for the other.